# Three.js merge with different textures

Tags: javascript, typescript, merge, three.js, textures

I have a scene with two individual meshes.
It looks like this:

[image]

```
    this.loadFiles("gras", (gras) => {
        var particleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
        particleMaterial.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("models/planets/gras.jpg");
        particleMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(gras,particleMaterial);
        this.loadFiles("rocks", (rocks) => {
            var particleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
            particleMaterial.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("models/planets/rocks.jpg");
            particleMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            this.rocks = new THREE.Mesh(rocks,particleMaterial);
            callback(this);
        });
    });
```

Now I want to merge the meshes together. But how can i combine the textures?

[image]

```
   this.loadFiles("gras", (gras) => {
        this.loadFiles("rocks", (rocks) => {
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry;
            THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(geometry,gras);
            THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(geometry,rocks);
            var particleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
            particleMaterial.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("models/planets/gras.jpg");
            particleMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,particleMaterial);
            callback(this);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It does not make any sense to merge geometries that will be rendered using different materials. The renderer will have to un-merge the geometry anyway.

Comment: Why not? I would create a merged texture file and a merged geometry. If I don't merge it the renderer has to take care of much more points, which the user can not see anyway.

Comment: I thought your title implied you want to use `THREE.MultiMaterial` with merged geometry... Do you want to use a single material with your merged geometry? Also, don't worry about performance unless you have a performance problem.

Comment: Oh, my fault! I did not know that THREE.MultiMaterial exists. Yes I want to create a single material with the textures from the other materials.

Comment: @WestLangley any ideas who i can implement this?