# Merging Text geometries in Three.js while keeping individual material colors

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to merge text geometries in Three.js (r84). I need to do so using multiMaterial and retaining individual colors for each text object. Here's a live demo. https://jsfiddle.net/5oydk6nL/

Thanks.

```
var $win = $( window ) ,
    $container = $( '#webGL-container' ) ,

    scene , camera , cameraTarget , renderer ,
    pointLight , hex ,
    stats , rendererStats ,

    typeface = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/redwavedesign/ca97268140e8a51633595cd34bb77f16/raw/46ae61687ac8e7e3af01ee2c983580f2b0b0809f/bebas_regular.json';



/* text objects */

var a = {
    text: 'a' ,
    color: 'red' ,
    x: -90
}

var b = {
    text: 'b' ,
    color: 'blue' ,
    x: -60
}

var c = {
    text: 'c' ,
    color: 'green' ,
    x: -30
}

var d = {
    text: 'd' ,
    color: 'yellow' ,
    x: 0
}

var e = {
    text: 'e' ,
    color: 'purple' ,
    x: 30
}

var f = {
    text: 'f' ,
    color: 'orange' ,
    x: 60
}

var g = {
    text: 'g' ,
    color: 'aqua' ,
    x: 90
}




// array with all text objects
var letters = [ a , b , c , d , e , f , g ];




function decimalToHex( d ) {

    var hex = Number( d ).toString( 16 );
    hex = "000000".substr( 0, 6 - hex.length ) + hex;
    return hex.toUpperCase();

}




function init() {


    /* create scene, camera and renderer */
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera =  new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40 , window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight , .1 , 1500 );
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

    /* setup renderer */
    renderer.setClearColor( '#ffffff' );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

    /* setup camera */
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = 500;

    cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0 , 0 , 0 );

    /* Lights */
    pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 2 );
    pointLight.position.set( 20 , -300 , 200 );
    scene.add( pointLight );

    pointLight.color.setStyle( '#EBEBEB' );
    hex = decimalToHex( pointLight.color.getHex() );


    // load each text object from the 'letters' array
    $.each( letters , function( index , letter ) {


        var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();


        // load font
        fontLoader.load( typeface , function ( font ) {


            var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( letter.text , {

                    font: font,
                    height: 8 ,
                    size: 28 ,
                    curveSegments: 4 ,
                    bevelThickness: 1,
                    bevelSize: 1.5 ,
                    bevelSegments: 3 ,
                    bevelEnabled: true ,
                    material: 0,
                    extrudeMaterial: 1

            });


            var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( [
                new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: letter.color , shading: THREE.FlatShading } ), // front
                new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: letter.color , shading: THREE.SmoothShading } ) // side
            ] );


            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry , material );


            mesh.position.set( letter.x , 0 , 0 );


            // add text object to scene
            scene.add( mesh );


        });


    // end of each loop
    });


    // add the rendered element to the page
    $container.append( renderer.domElement );


}




function render() {

    camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );

    renderer.clear();

    renderer.render( scene , camera );

}



function animate() {

    // begin Three.js stats utility
    stats.begin();

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

    // update Threex stats plugin
    rendererStats.update( renderer );

    // conclude sample for Three.js stats testing
    stats.end();

}



// performance monitoring

rendererStats = new THREEx.RendererStats();
rendererStats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
rendererStats.domElement.style.left = '0px'
rendererStats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px'
document.body.appendChild( rendererStats.domElement );

stats = new Stats();
    stats.showPanel( 0 );
    document.body.appendChild( stats.domElement );
    document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );



// initialize 
init();

// animate
animate();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to group all the letters, using `THREE.Group()`?

Comment: Would grouping objects improve performance? That was my reasoning for wanting to merge geometries. I haven't used group yet. Would I be able to move individual objects if they were grouped?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988213/three-js-merge-with-different-textures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988213/three-js-merge-with-different-textures) read comments from WestLangley there

Comment: @redwavedesign See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36389254/1461008

Comment: Tried to implement vertexColors as described by WestLangley, but haven't been able to get it working. If someone can whip up my jsfiddle example with the needed changes it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5oydk6nL/14/).

A few things needed to be added:

**1) create a multimaterial and add material for each letter:**

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: letter.color,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
});

multiMaterial.materials.push(material);
```

**2) add material index to all faces of each letter:**

```
for (var i = 0, il = geometry.faces.length; i < il; i++) {
    geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = index
}
```

**3) Translate the geometry x to the right using a transformation matrix:**

```
geometry.applyMatrix(
    matrix.makeTranslation(letter.x, 0, 0)
);
```

**4) Merge each letter geometry into a single geometry:**

```
mergedGeometry.merge(geometry);
```

Now you have one merged geometry:

[image]

---

**Note:** Try to prevent the use of jQuery inside your fiddle next time, this extra library is not necessary for your example. Also read [here in these guidelines for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It does not make sense to merge geometries that use different materials. Notice you still have 7 draw calls.

Comment: @WestLangley OK, I simply answered the question and this code does the job. But I am interested in your view on this. Could you explain what is the purpose of `THREE.MultiMaterial` if using it in such a case *"doesn't make sense"*? Are there other user cases where it does make sense to use this class? Could you elaborate in an answer. It would be useful if you share some more information about this.

Comment: (1) `MultiMaterial` exists as a user convience to suport loaders such as `OBJLoader` that supports material groups. (2) Only one shader may be used at a time by the GPU, so there must be a draw call for each material. (3) It can make sense to merge geometries that share the same material.

Comment: Which is where a good shaderMaterial can do wonders, solving the drawcall issue

Comment: @Hesha, thanks for your input. Could you elaborate on this? I could also ask another question where we could zoom in on this particular aspect of this question...

Comment: Yep, check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pisha/drxey8n8/), different colors, 1 drawcall. This simple shaderMaterial only works if the letter aren't moved on the x axis, but for the sake of example, it should do.

Comment: @Hesha Nice, a simple but awesome example. Would be cool to use something like that for a colored 3D graph where the z-coordinate determines the color of the vertices.

Comment: @Wilt Thanks for the help merging geometries while retaining individual object colors. While not more performant using MultiMaterial it will be elsewhere. I've removed unnecessary jQuery and have simplified the example to only use two colors, hoping to increase performance somehow. Is it possible to reduce calls being made to only one for each color, while retaining MultiMaterial and Shading? Thanks guys. https://jsfiddle.net/5oydk6nL/28/

Comment: @redwavedesign [Here a quick example on how to draw those characters with 2 draw calls](https://jsfiddle.net/5oydk6nL/29/).